# What type to use for generic decodable class

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I have some basics in Swift, and I'm now trying to learn iOS development. I'm currently working in a small app that will ask resource on an API I've made that returns json made from :

```
struct A : Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

struct B : Codable {
    let something: String
}
```

Both API and app have these structs defined. As I'm always querying the same API, I thought of wrapping the part that ask the API some resources and decode this so I have an instance of the struct to use in my callback. Here's this method :

```
static func getContent(urlRequest: URLRequest, decodable: Decodable, completion: @escaping (Codable?, ErrorEnum?)->Void) {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil, .noData) // Handling errors in an enum
            return 
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let full = try? decoder.decode(decodable, from: data) {
            completion(full, nil)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

My problem concerns the decodable param. This shows an error and prevent me from compiling the app. After finding some resources on StackOverflow, I tried to change the parameters as

```
static func getContent(urlRequest: URLRequest, decodable: Decodable.Type, completion: @escaping (Codable?, ErrorEnum?)->Void)
```

I also tried to keep the parameter like this, and instead change inside the decode params

```
if let full = try? decoder.decode(decodable, from: data) {
    completion(full, nil)
}
```

but nothing seems to satisfy the compiler... And looking at `decode` method inside Swift source code didn't help me that much as it requires `T.Type where T is Decodable`

My wish is to be able to use this as follow :

```
static func getA() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/a") else { return }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    getContent(urlRequest: urlRequest, decodable: A.self) {
        a, error in

        guard a = a else { return }
        print(a.name!)
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how I could achieve this ? I also don't really know how to call this type of parameters or what to search on google that can lead me to the answer (lack of vocabulary).

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this just add a `generic` `.Type` of `Codable`  and use its type as a parameter to pass `foo.self`

```
static func getContent<T: Codable>(urlRequest: URLRequest, decodable: T.Type, completion: @escaping (T?, ErrorEnum?)->Void) {
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
    data, response, error in

    guard let data = data else {
        completion(nil, .noData) // Handling errors in an enum
        return
    }
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let full = try? decoder.decode(decodable, from: data) {
        completion(full, nil)
    }
}
task.resume()
}
```

Comment: The `decodable` parameter is redundant, you can write `decoder.decode(T.self,...`

Comment: could you explain what you mean ?

Comment: its the parameter name

Comment: Delete `, decodable: T.Type` and replace `if let full = try? decoder.decode(decodable, from: data) {` with `if let full = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) {`. And you should call `completion` with an error also if the decoding fails

Comment: its the parameter as it should be the same type as the return object, i don't see the point here but i'll look into it later, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You don't need the parameter, the compiler can infer the type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I'm not quite familiar with generic type. I mark your answer as solution as I pretty much only have to copy / paste it. Do you have any idea why it works for T.Type where T is Codable and not Codable.Type ?

Comment: because you specify a type of that protocol like an object that conform to that protocol, when you use T , but when u use Codable directly it expect a protocol type rather than an instance of that type , and .Type is where you want to look for because you need to pass .self , instance type rather than object to decode with

Comment: also T is return value as the passed decodable should also be the return type rather  when you pass Foo, you expect Foo type as result

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
func genericRequest<T: Decodable>(_ request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping APIGenericRequestCompletion<T>) {

        Alamofire.request(request).responseData { (response) in


            guard let data = response.data else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }


            do {
                let decodedObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)

                completion(decodedObject)
            } catch {
                completion(nil)
            }

        }
    }
```

where APIGenericRequestCompletion is:

```
typealias APIGenericRequestCompletion<T: Decodable> = (_ result: T?) -> Void
```

Then you use it as:

```
genericRequest(request) { (decodableObjectResponse) in
            // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :)  
Do you have any idea why it works for T.Type where T is Codable and not Codable.Type ?